# Spring Failed to start component

Tags: java, spring

Начал изучать спринг, создал с помощью инициализатора проект и ввёл в него код-пример с этого  [сайта](http://spring-projects.ru/projects/spring-boot/). В итоге в проекте есть один класс:

DempApplication.class:

```
@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class DemoApplication {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    String home() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Пытаюсь запустить, но программа не работает. Выводит в лог такое сообщение:

```
2018-06-11 00:50:00.165 ERROR 6896 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]

org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:256) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:198) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:300) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) [spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at com.example.test.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:24) [classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1020) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:225) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:210) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:591) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1018) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    ... 19 common frames omitted

2018-06-11 00:50:00.169  INFO 6896 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-06-11 00:50:00.182  INFO 6896 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-06-11 00:50:00.184 ERROR 6896 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8080, or configure this application to listen on another port.

2018-06-11 00:50:00.185  INFO 6896 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@7c76ecc0: startup date [Mon Jun 11 00:49:56 YEKT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-06-11 00:50:00.187  INFO 6896 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Что делать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как выяснилось, проблема заключалась в том, что порт 8080 прослушивала какая-то программа.

Чтобы решить эту проблему (на windows), нужно поступить так:

1. Открываем `cmd` и вводим туда команду: `netstat -ano`.
2. В колонке `PID` смотрим на номер, который соответствует нужному порту (8080).
3. Чтобы избавиться от него, вводим: `taskkill -pid "номер" /f`.
4. Перезапускаем приложение.